# Purpose of Unity Application Block in Microsoft Enterprise Library?

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of the Unity Application Block?  I tried looking through the documentation but its all very abstract.

What are some practical uses for the Unity block?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Inversion of Control**

A quick summation (lot more reading is available this topic, and I highly suggest reading more)...

Microsoft's Unity from the Enterprise Patterns and Practices team is an Inversion of Control container project, or IoC for short.   Just like Castle Windsor, StructureMap, etc.  This type of development is also referred in lamen's terms as Loosely Coupling your components.

IoC includes a pattern for Dependency Injection of your objects, in which you rely on an external component to wire up the dependencies within your objects.

For example, instead of accessing static managers (which are near impossible to unit test), you create an object that relies on an external dependency to act upon.  Let's take a Post service in which you want to access the DB to get a Post.

```
public class PostService : IPostService
{
  private IPostRepository _postRepo;

  public PostService(IPostRepository postRepo)
  {
    _postRepo = postRepo;
  }

  public IList<Post> GetPosts()
  {
    return _postRepo.GetAllPosts().ToList();
  }
}
```

This PostService object now has an external dependency on IPostRepository.  Notice how no concretes and no static manager classes are used?  Instead, you have a *loose-coupling* of a simple Interface - which gives you the power of wiring up all different kinds of concrete classes that implement IPostRepository.

Microsoft Unity's purpose is to wire up that IPostRepository for you, automatically.  So you never have to worry about doing:

```
// you never have to do this with Unity
IPostRepository repo = new PostRepository();
IPostService service = new PostService(repo); // dependency injection
IList<Post> posts = service.GetPosts();
```

The above shows where you have to implement two concrete classes, PostRepository() and PostService().  That is tightly-coupling your application to demand/require those exact instances, and leaves it very difficult to unit test.

Instead, you would use Unity in your end point (The controller in MVC, or code behind in ASPX pages):

```
IUnityContainer ioc = new UnityContainer();
IPostService postService = ioc.Resolve<IPostService>();
IList<Post> posts = postService.GetPosts();
```

Notice that there are no concretes used in this example (except UnityContainer and Post, obviously)!  No concretes of the services, and no repository.  That is loosely-coupling at its finest.

*Here's the real kicker...*

Unity (or any IoC container framework out there!) will inspect IPostService for any dependencies.  It will see that it wants (depends) on an instance of IPostRepository.  So, Unity will go into it's object map and look for the first object that implements IPostRepository that was registered with the container, and return it (i.e. a SqlPostRepository instance).  That is the real power behind IoC frameworks - the power to inspect services and wire up any of the dependencies automatically.

I need to finish my blog post about the comparisons of UNity vs Castle vs StructureMap.  I actually prefer Castle Windsor due to its configuration file options, and extensibility points personally.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Over the years (wow, 2 years since I posted this answer) I have actually started to move away from Castle Windsor due to it's "If you call Resolve<T>(), you must call Release(Object)" inherit "It's not a bug, but a feature" issue.  That has caused a number of memory leaks in the apps I've written.

Instead, I'm moving to the MEF with a custom Contextual handling of WebRequests.

Answer (score 4):

The Unity Application Block is used for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I think the best simple definition for DI is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old/1638961#1638961)

> When you go and get things out of the refrigerator for yourself, you can cause problems. You might leave the door open, you might get something Mommy or Daddy doesn't want you to have. You might even be looking for something we don't even have or which has expired.
>
> What you should be doing is stating a need, "I need something to drink with lunch," and then we will make sure you have something when you sit down to eat.

So for an example,

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
ILunch lunch = container.Resolve<ILunch>();
Console.WriteLine(lunch.Drink);
```

This Outputs "Lemonade" because we defined `Drink` as a Dependency.

```
public class ILunch {
    [Dependency]
    public IDrink Drink { get; set; }
}
```

As far as practicality goes, Dependency Injection is really great when you have Dependencies on other objects and you don't want the developer to have to manually set them. It is that simple. It is also great for mocking. The most used example I can think of that I use is mocking a data layer. Sometimes the database isn't ready so instead of stopping development I have a fake layer that returns fake data. The data object is accessed via DI and can be configured to return objects which access the fake layer or the real layer. In this example I am almost using the DI Container as a configurable factory class. For more on Unity MSDN has some great resources http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468366.aspx.

Other good DI Frameworks include [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) and [Ninject](http://ninject.org/)