# Ent Lib Unity when to use

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

i've been trying to get  my head around on EntLib 5.1 Unity and it's confusing me a lot http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660864%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx.

Could anyone please tell me on what type of scenario I can use Unity?

I've a requirement to load the specific dll based on request type. Can Unity be used on this scenario?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Unity Application Block in Microsoft Enterprise Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712414/purpose-of-unity-application-block-in-microsoft-enterprise-library)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically loading DLLs, you may want to take a look at [MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057994/where-can-i-learn-about-mef).

Unity is for decoupling dependencies among classes to make it easier to write testable, reusable code.

It is an [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC) container library that makes it easier to do [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). There are numerous [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/help-with-dependency-injection-in-net) on Stack Overflow. Note that you can configure Unity in code (my preference) or with a configuration file.