#  What is AOP, Dependency Injection and Inversion Of Control in Simple English

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, aop

I have tried to understand AOP, Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control SPRING related concepts but I am having hard time understanding it.

Can anyone explain this in simple English ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I understand your confusion and it took me some time to understand how these concepts were related together. So here is my (somehow personal) explanation of all this:

**1. Inversion of Control**

[Inversion of control](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) is a design principle rather generic that refers to the decoupling of the specification of a behavior from when it is actually executed. Compare for instance,

```
myDependency.doThis();
```

with

```
myDependency.onEventX += doThis();
```

In the latter, there is *no direct invocation* which is more flexible. In its general form, inversion of control relates to the *observer pattern*, *events*, or *callbacks*.

**2. Dependency inversion**

Dependency inversion is another design principle. Roughly speaking, it says that higher-level abstraction should not depend directly on lower-level abstractions; this results indeed in a design where higher-level abstraction can not be reused without the lower-level abstractions.

```
 class MyHighLevelClass {
     MyLowLevelClass dep = new MyLowLeverClass();
 }

 class App {
     void main() {  new HighLevelClass().doStuff(); }
 }
```

Here, `MyHighLevelClass` can not compile without access to `MyLowLevelClass`. To break this coupling, we need to *abstract* the low level class with an interface, and remove the direct instantiation.

```
class MyLowLevelClass implements MyUsefulAbstraction { ... }

class MyHighLevelClass {

    MyUsefulAbstraction dep;

    MyHighLevelClass( MyUsefulAbstraction dep ) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }
}

class App {
     void main() {  new HighLevelClass( new LowLevelClass() ).doStuff(); }
 }
```

Note that you don't need anything special like a container to enforce dependency inversion, which is a principle. A good reading is [The Dependency Inversion Principle](https://drive.google.com/a/cleancoder.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgMjdlMWIzNGUtZTQ0NC00ZjQ5LTkwYzQtZjRhMDRlNTQ3ZGMz) by Uncle Bob.

**3. Dependency injection**

Now comes dependency injection. To me `dependency injection = IoC + dependency inversion`:

1. dependencies are provided externally so we enforce the dependency inversion principle
2. the container sets the dependencies (not us) so we speak of inversion of control

In the example I provided above, dependency injection can be done if a container is used to instantiate objects and automatically *inject* the dependency in the constructor (we speak then frequently of DI container):

```
 class App {
     void main() {  DI.getHighLevelObject().doStuff(); }
 }
```

Note that there are various [form of injections](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection). Note also that under this perspective, [setter injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#SetterInjectionWithSpring) can be seen as a form of callback -- the DI container creates the object then calls back the setter. The flow of control is effectively inverted.

**4. AOP**

Strictly speaking, AOP has little to do with the 3 previous points. The [seminal paper on AOP](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/papers/kiczales-ECOOP1997-AOP.pdf) is very generic and present the idea of weaving various sources together (possibly expressed with different languages) to produce a working software.

I won't expand more on AOP. What is important here, is that dependency injection and AOP do effectively plays nicely together because it makes the weaving very easy. If an IoC container and dependency injection is used to abstract away the instantiation of objects, the IoC container can easily be used to weave the aspects before injecting the dependencies. This would otherwise requires a special compilation or a special `ClassLoader`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has helped me but can you elaborate more on dependency inversion and compare with inversion of control, somehow am not able to understand this two concepts. Would appreciate useful examples to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 10):

Dependency injection was explained very well in  [How to explain dependency injection to a 5-year-old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old/1638961#1638961):

> When you go and get things out of the
>   refrigerator for yourself, you can
>   cause problems. You might leave the
>   door open, you might get something
>   Mommy or Daddy doesn't want you to
>   have. You might even be looking for
>   something we don't even have or which
>   has expired.
>
> What you should be doing is stating a
>   need, "I need something to drink with
>   lunch," and then we will make sure you
>   have something when you sit down to
>   eat.

AOP - Aspect Oriented Programming - basically means that the source you write is modified with other code, based on rules located ELSEWHERE.  This means that you can e.g. say "as the first line of every method I want a 'log.debug("entering *method()*")' in a central place and each and every method you compile with that rule in place will then have that line included.   The "aspect" is the name of looking on code in other ways than simply from first source line to last.

Inversion of Control basically means that you do not have a central piece of code controlling everything (like a giant switch in main()) but have a lot of pieces of code that "somehow" get called.  The subject is discussed at Wikipedia:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: Reason of the downvote is maybe that your answer doesn't address the *relationship* between these concepts, which is asked in the question and is the hard part. (I'm not the downvoter though.)

Answer (score 2):

These three are all different concepts, but they all work well together, and so Spring apps often make use of all of it at once.  I'll give you an example.

Let's say that we have a web application that can do many different things.  We could construct this application in many ways, but one way is to create a class that is in charge of doing each of these things.  We need to invoke and create these classes from somewhere.  One option is to have a big main class that creates one of each of these services, opens up a socket, and passes calls to these services as they come in.  Unfortunately, we've gone and created ourselves a god class, which has way too much logic and knows way too much about how everything in our program works.  If we change anything about our program, we're probably going to need to modify this class.

Also, it's difficult to test.  We can't test any class in isolation if it runs around instantiating and invoking the other classes directly.  Unit tests become much, much harder to write.

A way to get around this is to use inversion of control.  We say "okay, these are service classes.  Who instatiates them?  Not me."  Usually, each one defines an interface, like LoginService or BillingService.  There might be more than one implementation of that interface, but your app doesn't care.  It just knows that it can ask for a certain kind of a service or a service with a certain name, and it'll get something nice back.

Dependency injection allows us to wire all of our litle pieces together.  Classes have accessible fields, constructor arguments, or setter methods that are references to the other components that they'll need to access.  That makes unit testing much easier.  You can create the object under test, throw a mock or stub dependency at it, and then test that the object behaved correctly in isolation.

Now, our real application is a complex jumble of pieces that all need to be wired together just so.  There are many ways to accomplish this, including allowing the application to make guesses ("this class wants a UserService, there is exactly one other class I'm in charge of that implements UserService") or by carefully explaining how they wire together in XML or Java.  Spring, at its core, is a service that takes care of wiring these classes together.

Now we get to AOP.  Let us say that we have all of these classes that are wired to each other in elaborate ways.  There are some cross-cutting concerns that we might want to describe in very generic ways.  For instance, perhaps you'd like to start a database transaction whenever any service is invoked, and commit that transaction so long as the service doesn't throw an exception.  It turns out that Spring is in a unique position to perform such a task.  Spring can create proxy classes on the fly that implement whatever interface your classes need, and it can wrap your class in its proxy.  Now, IoC and dependency injection certainly aren't necessary to do aspect-oriented programming, but it's an extremely convenient way to accomplish it.

Comment: I am lost between difference of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control, I was under the impression that both terms refer to same thing, one is design pattern and other is implementation, can you correct my understanding or provide some more explanation with example ?

Comment: They're very closely related.  Dependency relation is a type of inversion of control.  There are several types of things that can have their control inverted, and one of those things is dependency management.  Other forms of inversion of control involve, for instance, letting an OS drive user interface widgets instead of an application itself.  Martin Fowler uses that example in the article where he coins the phrase "dependency injection": http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control is explained very well in

http://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html

("You mean Dependency Inversion, Right?" section)

The summary:

> DI is about how one object acquires a dependency. When a dependency
>   is provided externally, then the system is using DI.
>
> IoC is about who initiates the call. If your code initiates a call,
>   it is not IoC, if the container/system/library calls back into code
>   that you provided it, is it IoC.

Answer (score 1):

let me tell you some word about AOP, hope it make it simplier to understand.
The very base principle of AOP is finding common tasks/aspects which returns in 
many places in the code and dont belong to the concerete business of the code. For example
write to log on every entrance to any function, or when an object is created wrapp it, or send email to admin when calling to specific function. 
So instead of the programmers will handle these non businuss aspect we take it from them and
we manage these aspects behond the scene.
That all the basic of AOP on 1 leg....

Answer (score 1):

A simple comparison from Spring in Action:

> Whereas DI helps you decouple your application
>   objects from each other, AOP helps you decouple cross-cutting concerns from the
>   objects that they affect.