# Dependency Injection: should dependent objects passed as constructor args or not?

Tags: java, frameworks, dependency-injection

On the video here 
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

It explains that it should.

And here OscarRyz says the contrary
[How to explain dependency injection to a 5-year-old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old)

So I'm confused now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally prefer to use the fact that Constructors can naturally define all the mandatory fields and those fields which once set cannot be changed.  You can do the same with setters but there is no direct language support for this.

While I prefer using constructors for mandatory and final fields, I don't see this as something specific to dependency injection.

Comment: +1 Constructor Injection implies mandatory dependencies. Property Injection implies optional dependencies (which is kind of a weird concept, because it tends to break SRP).

Comment: Yeah I really prefer constructor.

Answer (score 5):

There is no simple answer. It depends on the situation. Check section **"Constructor versus Setter Injection"** in Martin Fowler's article:

http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html