# Java Class.forName won't compile. Getting "cannot find symbol symbol : method"

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to use Class.forName and my Intellij is throwing a compile error.  My IntelliJ highlights "theResponse" in red (in testMethod) and gives me this error:

```
cannot find symbol symbol : method
```

Here is the code (and test) I'm working with...

```
package http.response;

public class TestClass {
  public TestClass() {
    PublicRoute publicRoute = new PublicRoute();
  }

  public String testMethod() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class c = Class.forName("http.response.PublicRoute");
    return c.theResponse("hi");
  }

}

package http.response;

import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestClassTest {
  @Test
  public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    assertEquals("public", testClass.testMethod());
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  What I was trying to do was "polymorphically" call theResponse from the class that is returned **as a String** from a HashMap.  How would I do this?  I'm (loosely) following this example but I didn't understand it fully (http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).  Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.  Hopefully that makes sense.

```
package http.response;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestClass {
  HashMap map;

  public TestClass(HashMap map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  public String testMethod(String lookupValue) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String className = map.get(lookupValue);
    Class c = Class.forName("http.response." + className);
    return c.theResponse();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Class.forName()` returns an object of type `java.lang.Class`.  `java.lang.Class` has no method `theResponse`, as you can see from [its Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

It sounds like what you actually want to do is construct an instance of the `PublicRoute` class, and call the method on the instance.  But you've already constructed such an instance: it's the `publicRoute` variable you create in your constructor.  Why not just use that object instead?

---

**Edit**: Ah, I see what you're trying to do.  You basically want a form of the [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) pattern.

Create an interface, like so:

```
public interface ResponseProvider {
  String theResponse();
}
```

Then make all your classes implement that interface:

```
public class PublicRoute implements ResponseProvider {
  @Override
  public String theResponse() {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Then, when you load your `Class<?>`, you can use the [`asSubclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)) method to turn your `Class<?>` into a `Class<? extends ResponseProvider>` -- then `newInstance()` will give you back a `ResponseProvider` object that you can call `theResponse()` on, like so:

```
String className = ...;
Class<?> klass = Class.forName(className);
Class<? extends ResponseProvider> responseProviderClass
    = klass.asSubclass(ResponseProvider.class);
ResponseProvider responseProvider = responseProviderClass.newInstance();
return responseProvider.theResponse();
```

But don't do that by hand -- instead, use the [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class, which is designed for exactly this purpose.   You create a special `META-INF/services/com.my.package.ResponseProvider` file, with a list of all the possible classes that implement that interface, and then `ServiceLoader` can give you back instances of each of them.

But... consider not doing that, either.  The types of problems that you can solve with the Service Locator pattern are often better solved by using [Dependency Injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (see also [my answer to another question about Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection/14301816#14301816)).  The [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) DI framework, for example, offers a feature called [multibindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) which looks like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If `theResponse()` belongs to `http.response.PublicRoute` then it should have been

```
Class c = Class.forName("http.response.PublicRoute");
return ((PublicRoute) c.newInstance()).theResponse("hi");
```

But, then there's really no need for `Class.forName()` as you could use constructor as

```
return new PublicRoute().theResponse("hi");
```

Answer (score 2):

The class `Class` does not have a method named `theResponse`. From the rest of your code, it doesn't look like you should be using reflection here; you're already referring statically to the `PublicRoute` class, so there's no point loading it dynamically.

I think you just want to write either this:

```
return PublicRoute.theResponse("hi");
```

or this:

```
return new PublicRoute().theResponse("hi");
```

(depending whether `theResponse` is a static method or an instance method).

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand what you're trying to do.  You've got a hashmap that will contain a list of classes that you're going to try to call the `theResponse(String response)` method on, right? I'm assuming you won't know the String that will be put into the hashmap either, right?

Others are right in that you can't just do:

```
Class c = Class.forName("http.response.PublicRoute");
c.theResponse("hi"); // errors because c has no knowledge of theResponse()
```

You'll need to cast c to `http.response.PublicRoute` but then as @Ravi Thapliyal pointed out, you won't need `Class.forName` anymore!  You've got a hashmap of names that could potentially be anything so this won't work.

If I'm understanding you correctly to do what you need, you'll need to use reflection in order to attempt to instance the class then call the method on it.

Here's how you'd do it assuming the `theResponse` method is a public non-static method and has only 1 parameter.

```
// Declare the parameter type
Class[] paramString = new Class[1]; 
paramString[0] = String.class;

String className = map.get(lookupValue);

// Instance the class
Class cls = Class.forName("http.response." + className);
Object obj = cls.newInstance();

// Call the method and pass it the String parameter
method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("theResponse", paramString);
method.invoke(obj, new String("hi"));
```

Of course you'll need to handle Exceptions but you'd surround the above code with the loop for your hashmap.

I hope this helps!