# ASP.NET MVC Global DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set the variable DB as global and use anywhere.
My problem is that I'm initialising twice the db. In the base controller and in atributes.
ie:

```
public class SettingsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
  public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
[Settings]
public class BaseController : Controller {
  public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
    ...
}
```

I would like to create the var db just once, and access anywhere in the project.
How ca I do this?

Comment: do not use "global db context" and "asp.net" in the same sentence. How are you disposing of the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about putting it in another class (an Helper, for instance), and access it like this:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = null;
public ApplicationDbContext Db {
    get {
        if (db == null)
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        return db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using of [Dependency Injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). For .NET there is for example [Unity container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff647202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which implements a lightweight, extensible dependency injection container. Check the [List of dependency injection containers for .NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx), but it's quite old.

In general, Dependency injection is called **Inversion of Control** (IoC). That means, your classes, which are using for example your DB class, don't need to be dependent on a specific DB class. Instead, they just require a specific interface. DB class implementing this interface is injected from the outside and your class is decoupled from a specific implementation of DB class.

Some places to start with:

- [Dependency Injection on Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- [Why does one use dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection)
- [An Absolute Beginner's Tutorial on Dependency Inversion Principle, Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver)
- [Dependency Injection in Windows Communication Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273093(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: promoting DI , IoC and DP is always a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this situation and (similar situations) is to implement a `DI/IoC pattern` , as @Dawid-Ferenczy mentioned in his answer. if you never worked with it before , it's a little abstract at the beginning but it's very useful in the long run , especially if your objects got complicated. You can search online for articles to learn more about the pattern itself.

@Dawid-Ferenczy mentioned the Unity container, but it's not limited to that , you can use any container you would like (Or even create your own if you need to ).
I personally use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) as it has a has a lot of support documentation and i found it easy to implement.

In your case (DB context)  i would use `Ninject` and `DI/IoC` as follow:

1- Declare an interface for your DB Context DAL:

```
  public interface IModelDBContext
    {
//Your methods should go here
    }
```

2. Your concrete class:

   public class ModelDBContext : DbContext,IModelDBContext
       {
       //Your methods and other stuff here
       }

---

### Container part

(Ninject in my case , but you can use any other container)

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
    //Bunch of initialization and methods 
    Check out this : [Using ninject in MVC][2].
    //Binding piece (Very important)
     private void AddBindings()
            {
                //Context DB Binding
                kernel.Bind<IModelDBContext>().To<ModelDBContext>();
                //Other binding
            }
    }
```

---

### Implementation part:

This is the fun and exciting part. anywhere in your application , if you need to implement your specific DB context you inject it with the constructor and it will be available for you to use:

In your case it will be something like this:

```
    Public YourConcreteClass
    {
    Private IModelDBContext ModelDB; //Initiate an instance that you will use .


//DI by constructor
public YourConcreteClass(IModelDBContext mDB)
        {
    ModelDB=mDB;

        }
//in the rest of your code you call ModelDB that has access to all of the methods and attributes you might need

    }
```