# why dependency injection pattern in unit test is best when compared to other patterns in c# mstest?

Tags: c#

I am new to unit testing and i need to use dependency injection pattern.

Comment: What other patterns? Why do you *need* to use it? I do not get the question.

Comment: Using dependency injection in your _code_ can help you to write _testable_ code. You don't need to use it, and whether dependency injection is best for your code (not unit tests) depends on the application

Comment: If You have complex system, than DI can shine. You can decompose the system into smaller components, which can be tested separately. Most likely You don't have that complex software at Your hand. Please try to specify a case, where You have problem, and ask that as a question

Comment: Please explain yourself better, this barley seems like a question.

Comment: There are 3 types of DI; class constructor, method parameter and property.  Pick on for your _code_, preferring the methods in the order given, and then use the class in the test.  The choice is made when writing code, not tests.

Comment: @RobinHames I believe you mean DI frameworks are used in _code_, but not in _tests_.  If the dependencies are injected in the code, they will have to be injected in the tests -- but a DI framework should not be used in the tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does one use dependency injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency injection for testing is not really a requirement, but it will really help in unit testing with providing some facilities like the injection of mocks but you could do it manually, it help use of interfaces, no new(), and no singletons etc ...

[please see the detailed example in this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/unit-test-using-mock-object-in-dependency-injection/)

Comment: But why is it best when compared to other like service locator etc.

Comment: Main objectives of UNIT testing is Test functional units in isolation, this can be done if you can pass dependencies from outside (DI). With the ServiceLocator, the class is still responsible for creating its dependencies. It uses the service locator to do it. With DI, the class is given it's dependencies. It neither knows, nor cares where they come from. One important result of this is that the DI example is much easier to unit test -- because you can pass it mock implementations of its dependent objects. You could combine the two and inject the service locator (or a factory), if you wanted.