# How to add a property that will be passed through more than one class

Tags: c#, class, properties, reference

I am currently creating a programme that will be based on a virtual cell simulation. For this I have seperate classes called machine, worksettingstation, robot and component. I need to be able to pass a component through each class depending on where it is in the cell. How would I create a property to do this? Also when it leaves the specific class it will return null as the component has moved. This will eventually move to a WPF but at the moment I'm just trying to show it in a simple class.

Is there a way I can simply just add a new property to each class and then reference it to the class called component and do a simple check to see if it has been passed on yet?

Comment: Declare a property in an Interface and them implement the interface in all the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing an Interface in the concrete classes and combining that with Dependency Injection should be the best way to achieve this.

**Dependency Injection :**
[Why does one use dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection)