# What is the difference between using the Service Locator anti-pattern and using the Castle Windsor container?"

Tags: oop, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, service-locator

Recently, I have been trying to understand what is the difference between using the Service Locator "anti-pattern" and using the Castle Windsor container. I have found some info here and there on the Internet and I have summarized what I have learned so far in [an unfinished blog post](http://1000linesofcode.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/dependencies-management/).

EDIT: Until now I have been thinking that Dependency Injection is all one would need to guarantee separation. But everywhere I look I see a push in the direction of containers such as Castle Windsor. I would like to clearly understand the reasons.
Please... [Explain this to me like I'm a 6 year old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-Pj2GfdkSc) :)

Comment: Which software did you use for your diagrams?

Comment: yUML: http://yuml.me/

Comment: I've attempted to answer that question here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics

Comment: While both answers so far are correct, I wish I could give the bounty to @MarkSeemann, because it's thanks to him that I have finally understood the concept of composition root and therefore the difference between DI containers and Service Locators. Mark, can you add an answer that explains what I just added at the end of my blog post, please? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Funny you should ask to have it explained like you were six years old; here's an [explanation like you were five years old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638961/126014) :)

> everywhere I look I see a push in the direction of containers such as Castle Windsor

Frankly, I think the reason for that is that most people actually don't understand what Dependency Injection is, which means that instead of grasping the concept of Inversion of Control, they go looking for a replacement for the `new` keyword they're already used to. Then they find a DI Container and (mis)use it as a Service Locator. Unfortunately, that's very easy to do.

This is the reason why, in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501), I explain all the DI concepts without coupling the explanation to any single DI Container. That's actually the majority of the book.

Service Locator and Dependency Injection are [two fundamentally different attempts at achieving loose coupling](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection). Service Locator has many disadvantages, and offers no advantages not also offered by DI. This is why I think it's safe to call Service Locator an anti-pattern.

You don't need a DI Container to use DI; in fact, I would say that [unless you take a rather sophisticated approach, it's probably better to avoid one](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer).

Comment: @MichaelKohne Sorry, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Well a service locator may just be a wrapper around a particular inversion of control container such as Castle Windsor. The point is that the only place in which your code should (ideally) reference the container is at your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Because inversion of control containers support dependency chaining, when you resolve your root type from the container, all of its dependencies will be injected, and any descendent dependencies.

If you then wish to create further types at run time, then you can use factories, which could also have a reference to your container if you wish to take advantage of the dependency chaining offered by the container and the container mappings of interfaces against implementations.

Answer (score 3):

When you use service locator, your code is calling locator for services everywhere. When you use inversion of control, there is only one place (composition root), where you call container. The rest of your app should not be container aware.

Comment: When you said "container aware" did you mean "unaware"?

Comment: ups "should not be container aware" :)