# Angular2: Dependency Injection at the instance level

Tags: angular

(I'm sorry that the next paragraph is going to be hard to parse. I find this always happens when describing DI).

I have an existing component, call it `Widget`.

`Widget` receives a `Thingy` via ng2 DI. And `Thingy`, in turn, receives a `ThingyPart` via DI.

Now I am writing a new component, call it `WidgetList`. `WidgetList` is ultimately going to enter a loop and create multiple `Widget`s. The main thing that is different about each of these `Widget`s is that they each need to have a different `ThingyPart` injected into their `Thingy`.  `WidgetList`, and only `WidgetList`, knows how to construct those `ThingyPart`s, and it needs the current loop variable in order to construct.

Ultimately what needs to happen is that I need to Provide a different `ThingyPart` per loop iteration. Is there any way to achieve this without touching `Widget`?

Alternative question: I notice that I can [receive the raw Injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#summary) in my WidgetList. Is there a way to dynamically add and remove the child injectors that my viewchildren see using the injector API? If there is, then I can create a new child injector in the loop and delete off the old one.  (You know what would be cool? A "provide" template directive that does this for me.)

Comment: is `Thingy` an angular component?

Comment: No, it's an @Injectable. Just a service

Comment: I'd avoid DI on `Thingy` and just Instantiate it in `Widget`. This sounds like a composition vs dependency question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022012/difference-between-dependency-and-composition

Comment: There are umpteen ways to make this work if I touch `Widget`. But that rather defeats the point of DI, because it makes `Thingy` into `Widget`'s concern when it really isn't.  I mean if DI can't do this, why the hell am I bothering?

Comment: Sure, but how is DI helping in this situation?

Comment: Well, at the moment, it's definitely not. In fact, I've already basically done what you've suggested:  `@Input thingyPartOverride: ThingyPart` inside of `Widget`, and then construct a `Thing` inside of `Widget` if `thingyPartOverride` is set. But, I mean, wow. It just feels bad.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like in the WidgetList component, you need to provide ThingyPart as a factory. Then, you can create instances of ThingyPart using data from WidgetList.

eg.

```
  @Component({
     selector: 'widget-list',
    .....
    providers: [
      { provide: ThingConfigService, useFactory: (widget ) => {
         ...  // use the Widget here to configure ThingConfigService as you need
              // then you can use ThingConfigService within your ThingyPart
              // and pull out the data that you need
         }, deps: [ Widget ]   
      }
    ]
 ......
```

That useFactory option accepts a function that can return your configured ThingyPart.  It's hard to guide you further without understanding more of what you're trying to accomplish.

[Thoughtram has an article about dependency injection that may prove useful](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: How can I use the data from my WidgetList instance inside of the factory method? Factories were one of the first things I looked at, but that factory function has nothing useful: `this` is undefined, and I can't get it to inject anything except what's available in parent containers, let alone what I really need, which is the loop variable.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CxMPf3?p=info   that plunker is trying to show what you can do with the useFactory option.  Note that you have to provide a service that you then configure in the useFactory function with what you need (you can't 'provide' the component itself - i'll update my answer to reflect that)